# Sublime [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3, sublime-jslint

On sublime text I'm getting following error while trying to validate JS.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'node'
[cmd: ['node', '/Users/gurpreetsingh/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/JSLint/linter.js', '--sloppy', '--indent', '2', '--node', '--nomen', '--vars', '--plusplus', '--stupid', '--todo', '/Users/gurpreetsingh/Documents/dev/aimia/infrastructure/endeavour-callcentre/endeavour-callcentre-web/src/main/webapp/js/modules/membervalidation.js']]
[dir: /Users/gurpreetsingh/Documents/dev/aimia/infrastructure/endeavour-callcentre/endeavour-callcentre-web/src/main/webapp/js/modules]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]


//Additional Information 
Node version :v0.10.13
which node: /usr/local/bin/node
echo $PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sublime can't find node, because as its `path` listing shows, it's not looking in `/usr/local/bin`. You need to modify the settings to point to `/usr/local/bin/node`, not just `node`, and you'll be all set.

Comment: Where do I need to change these settings?

Comment: which sublime-jslint plugin are you using? There are two.

Comment: Not sure, how can I find out?

Comment: Open Package Control with cmd+shift+p, then type `PCL` to get to "Package Control: List Packages". Hit enter, then type in `jslint`. The package name (in large letters, at the top) should either be "JSLint" or "sublime-jslint"

Comment: It's JSlint, +1 for trying to help me.

Comment: No problem. Open `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/JSLint/JSLint.sublime-build` and add `/usr/local/bin/` to the `node` command on line 3. Save the file, and you should be all set.

Comment: No JSlint in packages I afraid :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34698/discussion-between-mattdmo-and-runtimeexception)

Answer (score 13):

I was able to get node working by downloading and installing node at (nodejs.org), then modifying the Sublime Text 2 build system using this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file", "$file_base_name"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "*.js"
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 4):

Go to:

Preferences > Package Settings > JSLint > Advanced Build Settings

Then set the node path as you have it installed. If you don't know, just type "which node" in the terminal to find out the correct path.

Comment: no such navigation on JSlint in Key bindingd and user settings (User and default)are there. how to do in sublime text3

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell JSLint package where your node is. Take Sublime Text 2 on Mac OS X for example, you need to open file `/Users/shawnzhu/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/JSLint/JSLint.sublime-build` and update the first element of the array value of the key `cmd` like this:

```
"/usr/local/bin/node"
```

Then save this file and re-run your Sublime text

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, If you are using Sublime Text 2, there are multiple ways to fix this problem:

1. You can see the last paragraph in the official [documentation](https://github.com/darrenderidder/Sublime-JSLint).
2. You can manually hack it by following these instructions (if the first method didn't work):

   ```
   vim ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/JSLint/JSLint.py
   ```

   then in line 16 you can see the `path` variable like this:

   ```
   if os.name == "posix":
       path = "/usr/local/bin:" + os.environ['PATH']
   else:
   ```

   prepend your path to the first string. e.g. if you are using `macports` to install your node:

   ```
   path = "/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:" + os.environ['PATH']
   ```

Don't forget to remove

```
rm ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/JSLint/JSLint.pyc
```

that is in the same directory.

Comment: you prepend the same string `/opt/local/bin` OR do we need to prepend nodejs path `/usr/bin/nodejs`

Comment: #2 Worked for me in ST3 too.